# Why is AMQP a two-way RPC protocol?

Tags: rabbitmq, mq, pika

I read the Pika doc, but I am not quite understand why it says "AMQP a two-way RPC protocol, where the client can send requests to the server and the server can send requests to a client...". Can anyone give me an example please ?

Does it mean when we create a exchange.

client sends: exchange.declare
server replies: exchange.declare-ok

Are these two method requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular example `exchange.declare` is client request and  `exchange.declare-ok` is server response.

Though, there are some methods that server can send to client, e.g. `basic.deliver`, `basic.return`, `connection.blocked` (RabbitMQ-specific extension).